# Async/Await - Vicious Circle C# 5.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

The code is below.

I want to call DoLongWork function asynchronously.

But the code ends up synchronous because DoLongWork doesn't **await** anything.

There is no need for awaiting something in DoLongWork function. Because function **itself** is long running. Not waiting any resource.

How can I get out of this vicious circle?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<int> task = Foo("Something");
            Console.WriteLine("Do it");
            Console.WriteLine("Do that");
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Ending All");
        }
        static async Task<int> Foo(string param)
        {
            Task<int> lwAsync = DoLongWork(param);
            int res = await lwAsync;
            return res;
        }

        static async Task<int> DoLongWork(string param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Long Running Work is starting");
            Thread.Sleep(3000); // Simulating long work.
            Console.WriteLine("Long Running Work is ending");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: “I want to call DoLongWork function asynchronously.” Why?

Comment: Because it is long running and this is my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) to execute synchronous work on a background thread:

```
// naturally synchronous, so don't use "async"
static int DoLongWork(string param)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Long Running Work is starting");
    Thread.Sleep(3000); // Simulating long work.
    Console.WriteLine("Long Running Work is ending");
    return 0;
}

static async Task<int> FooAsync(string param)
{
    Task<int> lwAsync = Task.Run(() => DoLongWork(param));
    int res = await lwAsync;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: OK, you put the filler answer. Wehere is the rest?

Comment: So why should I use async/await? Classical Task.Run can do what you suggest.

Comment: @AhmetAltun: If your `FooAsync` method is literally as simple as this example, then there's no point in using `async`/`await` here. You should only use `await` when you have some asynchronous operation to wait on.

Comment: @AhmetAltun You're asking that? In your question, you said you want to do that. You shouldn't modify your code if you don't have a good reason to do that.

Comment: Let me clarify my question. Give me an example that uses async/await pattern and NOT accessing framework async functions or async functions of outer resources. All methods should be implemented within your code.

Comment: @AhmetAltun: You should only use `async` if you *need* to `await` something. All asynchronous methods (whether framework or your own) end up at one of the primitives: `TaskCompletionSource` (or one of its shorthands such as `TaskFactory.FromAsync`, `Task.FromResult`, `Task.Delay`, etc) or `Task.Run` (or its longhand `TaskFactory.StartNew`).

Comment: Ok. This is what makes this pattern totally useless

Comment: @AhmetAltun: `async` was designed for asynchronous programming. If you're doing asynchronous programming, `async` is incredibly useful. If you're not, then it's not. Saying `async` is "totally useless" (for synchronous programs) is like saying ASP.NET is "totally useless" (for desktop applications).